# Want to find xPath of Last Column on the Basis of Previous Table Row Field Name

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Table Details [Table HTML Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncFpG.png)

```
//td/div\[text()='abc@gmail.com'\]//following-sibling::td/div\[@title='Action'\]
```

Table Details [Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oERJ.png)

Xpath so that on the basic of text enter by user it automatically select last cell of that particular row

Comment: Please share the HTML in the form of text not image.